# Bug - can’t reinstall elemetary

Tags: system-installation, bugs

I need urgent help.

There was a bug (I think) on my elementary os. When i tried to restar it didn't recognize any operating system. I tried to reinstall elementary from my flash drive (as i did before) and it opens on the “try” mode but cannot install it. The message is: “No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partition menu”. I added a new partition table, but the message was the same.

Background story: I installed elementary os on my notebook about 6 months ago. I save all my documents and works in an external drive. This past week I used my external drive on my friend’s computer (windows). When I came back home and tried to use my notebook (I use linux only) this happened (i don't know if it is related).

I only know the basics of linux. I need help “for dummies”.
And im fucked because i have to finish an article for tomorrow!
So please!!! Does anybody can help me?

The error was something like: [5828.052079] EXT4-fs error (device sda2) ext4-find:entry....

And some other things I could not capture

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

First, I tried to reinstall elementary os from my USB stick - didn't work. The USB stick stopped working too.

Then I download OpenSuse in another USB stick. It worked on trial mode but it didn't find any directory on my computer. Therefore, it did not install anything on my computer.

Then I tried to install Manjaro. It didn't work, but a new message started to show on my screen about a bug in BIOS and initramfs. (before there was a message about no directory found). **This was the turning point for me to fix it.** Unfortunately, I don't know how it happened.

After, I followed this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xf

Basically, you need to type: fsck /dev/sda1

It didn't work with sda1, so it tried with sda2. It worked!!

I followed the rest of the video (just type yes for everything). Then, type reboot. Then select the option *elementary, and that was it. My Notebook started to work again as it was before. Elementary was working as if anything has happened. I did not lose any of my packages.

I don't know what or how it happened but it worked. Above is exactly what I did. Probably most of it has nothing to do with the solution.

One more thing. The problem started after I tried to updated my elementary os. I did not try to update again.